# Transmission Line: characteristic impedance matching

Tags: transmission-line, impedance-matching, matching

The textbook explains a situation in which when you have 2 unmatched transmission lines (different characteristic impedance), you can connect a new line in between such that the input impedance would match.

Say I have a line #1 with characteristic impedance \$Z_1=100 \Omega\$.

Line #1 is connected to Line #3 with \$Z_3=20 \Omega\$. There is mismatch and therefore reflection.

If I connect another transmission in between and its length is the quarter wavelength, then this new transmission line (we call it Line #2) would match the characteristic impedance of Line #1.

\$ Z_2=\sqrt{Z_1\times Z_3}=\sqrt{100 \times 20}=44.7 \Omega \$.

\$Z_{in}=\frac{Z_2^2}{Z_3}=\frac{44.7^2}{20}=100 \Omega\$.

Thus, overall input impedance at the junction of Line #1 and Line #2 \$Z_{in}\$ would be equal to \$Z_1\$. Therefore, no reflection at this junction.

**But my question is**: what about at the junction of Line #2 and Line #3? Since \$Z_2=44.7 \Omega\$ is not equal to \$Z_3=20\Omega\$, then there will be reflection at their junction? If that is the case, what is the point of using matching?

Answer (score 8):

There will be a reflection at the junction between lines 2 and 3. In fact, there has to be for this to work.

What you're doing is you're choosing the \$Z_0\$ of line 2 so that the reflection at the 2/3 transition after propagating back to the 1/2 junction, exactly cancels the reflection at the 1/2 transition. You are setting up destructive interference for the reflected waves and constructive interference for the transmitted waves.

Note that because line 2 has to be one quarter wavelength in length, this technique can only work perfectly at one specific frequency.

Comment: Plus some multiple half wavelength ?

Answer (score 8):

Impedance matching is tricky, but the role of a quarter wave transmission line is to map from one impedance to another. The actual impedance of the line will not match either the input or the output impedance - this is entirely expected.

However at a given frequency, when a correctly designed quarter wave line is inserted with the correct impedance, the output impedance will appear to the input as perfectly matched. In your case, the transformer will make the  \$20\Omega\$ impedance appear as if it is a \$100\Omega\$ impedance meaning no mismatch. Essentially it guides the waves from one characteristic impedance to another.

The easiest way to visualise this is on a Smith chart, plot the two points 0.4 (\$20\Omega\$) and 2 (\$100\Omega\$). Then draw a circle centred on the resistive/real axis (line down the middle) which intersects both points. You will find that this point is located at 0.894 (\$44.7\Omega\$) if your calculations are correct. This is shown below at \$500\mathrm{MHz}\$, but the frequency is only important when converting the electrical length to a physical length.

[image: Smith Chart of Quarter Wave]

What a quarter wave transformer does is rotate a given point by \$180^\circ\$ around its characteristic impedance on the Smith chart (that's \$\lambda/4 = 90^\circ\$ forward plus \$90^\circ\$ reverse).

Exactly why it does this is complex. But the end result of a long derivation is that for a transmission line of impedance \$Z_0\$ connected to a load of impedance \$Z_L\$ and with a length \$l\$, then the impedance at the input is given by:

$$Z_{in}=Z_0\frac{Z_L+jZ_0\tan\left(\beta l\right)}{Z_0+jZ_L\tan\left(\beta l\right)}$$

That is an ugly equation, but it just so happens if the electrical length \$\beta l\$ is \$\lambda/4\$ (\$90^\circ\$), the \$\tan\$ part goes to infinity which allows the equation to be simplified to:

$$Z_{in}=Z_0\frac{Z_0}{Z_L}=\frac{(Z_0)^2}{Z_L}\rightarrow Z_0=\sqrt{\left(Z_{in}Z_L\right)}$$

Which is where your calculation comes from.

With the quarter wave transformer in place, the load appears as matched to the source. In other words, the transformer matches **both** of its interfaces, not just the input end.

You can also see from this equation why the transformer only works for a single frequency - because it relies on the physical length being \$\lambda/4\$. You can actually (generally using advanced design tools) achieve an approximate match over a range of frequencies - basically a close enough but not exact match.

Comment: What tool did you use to simulate this please ?

Comment: @Board-Man It's the "Smith-Chart" software by "Fritz Dellsperger". You can find it [here](http://www.fritz.dellsperger.net/smith.html).